# radios button help

Tags: 7, forms

I have a radio button called 'phone_number_y_n'. The values are 0 = India, 1 = US, 2=UK, 3=Canada. I want to check the value (which button the user selected) and process based on that.

It seems a simple thing, but i am not able to find how can i do that check $form_state['values']['phone_number_y_n'] is not working. I don'e see any #values option when I do the dpm of $form_state.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

function formalter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){


  if($form_id == "form1_node_form"){

    $form['field_province'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Provience',
       '#type'    => 'select',
       '#options' => _load_province(),
       '#ajax'    => array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback' =>'formalter_dropdown_city',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-field-city',
            'method' => 'replace',
            )
      );

  $options2 = array(
    0 => t('Zero'), 
    1 => t('One'), 
    2 => t('Two'), 
    3 => t('Three'),
       );

  $form['field_city'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'City',
       '#type'   => 'select',
       '#options' => $options2,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-city">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  $options3 = array(
    0 => t('India'), 
    1 => t('US'), 
    2 => t('UK'), 
    3 => t('Canada'),
       );

    $form['field_phone_number_y_n'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Phone number Y/N',
       '#type'    => 'radios',
       '#options' => $options3,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number-y-n">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
       '#ajax'    => array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback' =>'formalter_phonenumber',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-field-phone-number',
            'method' => 'replace',
            )
      );

    $form['field_phone_number'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Phone number',
       '#type'    => 'hide',
       '#value'   => 'none',
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

 }

}

function formalter_dropdown_city($form, $form_state) {

  $options2 = _load_city($form_state['values']['field_province']);
  $form['field_city'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'City',
       '#type'   => 'select',
       '#options' => $options2,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-city">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  return $form['field_city'];
}

function formalter_phonenumber($form, $form_state) {

  $options3 = $form_state['values']['field_phone_number_y_n'];

  $form['field_phone_number'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'Phone number',
       '#type'    => 'textfield',
       '#value' => $options3,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  return $form['field_phone_number'];
}

function _load_province() {
  $province = array('- Select province -');

  $query = db_select("sandbox_province", "a");
  $query->fields("a", array('id', 'name'));
  $query->condition("a.status", 1);
  $query->orderBy("a.name");
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($row = $result->fetchObject()){
    $province[$row->id] = $row->name;
  }

  return $province;
}


function _load_city($province_id) {
  $city = array('- Select city -');

  $query = db_select("sandbox_city", "a");
  $query->fields("a", array('id', 'name'));
  $query->condition("a.status", 1);
  $query->condition("a.province_id", $province_id);
  $query->orderBy("a.name");
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($row = $result->fetchObject()){
    $city[$row->id] = $row->name;
  }

  return $city;
}
```

Also, i want to display the label associated with the selected radio button instead of the value 0,1,2 or 3.

Comment: $form_state['values']['phone_number_y_n'] will either have the value 0 or 1 depending on what you have selected. Are you sure that this is not the case?

Comment: This code is in  my custom form_alter module. When I do dpm($form_state['values']['phone_number_y_n']), i get undefined index.  But I am selecting one of the radio buttons, the default is set to "No".

Comment: could you paste the code for clarity

Comment: I re-posted question with the code, please see this

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57365/drupal-7-radios-button-in-form-alter-module-with-ajax

Comment: In any AJAX callback you should take the reference of $form_state variable, like this: formalter_phonenumber($form, &$form_state)

Answer (score 1):

put the field_phone_number in an if condition as given below with  (This is inside the formalter_form_alter function where you have placed the hidden field. that should be removed and place the below code.

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_phone_number_y_n'])) 
{
    $options3 = $form_state['values']['field_phone_number_y_n'];

  $form['field_phone_number'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'Phone number',
       '#type'    => 'textfield',
       '#value' => $options3,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );
}
```

Now the call back should simply return the field_phone_number so your callback funtion would be.

```
function formalter_phonenumber($form, $form_state) {

  return $form['field_phone_number'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value within the form you should use [ajax](http://drupal.org/node/752056) for that.

See ajax_example in the examples module for simple implementations similar to yours.

During submit, in form_submit the $form_state will have $form_state['values'].

If you want the value outside, you can use [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)