# drupal 7 radios button in form_alter module with AJAX

Tags: forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [drupal 7 radios button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57186/drupal-7-radios-button)

I have a radio button called 'phone_number_y_n'. The values are 0 = India, 1 = US, 2=Uk, 3=Canada. I want to check the value (which button the user selected) and process based on that.

It seems a simple thing, but i am not able to find how can i do that check $form_state['values']['phone_number_y_n'] in the form_alter it is not working. I don'e see any #values option when I do the dpm of $form_state. However the AJAX module, i am able assign the values, but there also i don't see $form_state['values']

Also when i select the radio button, i am assigning the value and displaying that value 0,1,2,3 in phone_number field. But I actually want to display its associated label: India, US, UK, Canada

Here is the code

```
<?php

function formalter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){


  if($form_id == "form1_node_form"){

    $form['field_province'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Provience',
       '#type'    => 'select',
       '#options' => _load_province(),
       '#ajax'    => array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback' =>'formalter_dropdown_city',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-field-city',
            'method' => 'replace',
            )
      );

  $options2 = array(
    0 => t('Zero'), 
    1 => t('One'), 
    2 => t('Two'), 
    3 => t('Three'),
       );

  $form['field_city'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'City',
       '#type'   => 'select',
       '#options' => $options2,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-city">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  $options3 = array(
    0 => t('India'), 
    1 => t('US'), 
    2 => t('UK'), 
    3 => t('Canada'),
       );

    $form['field_phone_number_y_n'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Phone number Y/N',
       '#type'    => 'radios',
       '#options' => $options3,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number-y-n">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
       '#ajax'    => array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback' =>'formalter_phonenumber',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-field-phone-number',
            'method' => 'replace',
            )
      );

    $form['field_phone_number'] = array (
       '#title'   => 'Phone number',
       '#type'    => 'hide',
       '#value'   => 'none',
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

 }

}

function formalter_dropdown_city($form, $form_state) {

  $options2 = _load_city($form_state['values']['field_province']);
  $form['field_city'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'City',
       '#type'   => 'select',
       '#options' => $options2,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-city">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  return $form['field_city'];
}

function formalter_phonenumber($form, $form_state) {

  $options3 = $form_state['values']['field_phone_number_y_n'];

  $form['field_phone_number'] = array(
       '#title'   => 'Phone number',
       '#type'    => 'textfield',
       '#value' => $options3,
       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-field-phone-number">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',

   );

  return $form['field_phone_number'];
}

function _load_province() {
  $province = array('- Select province -');

  $query = db_select("sandbox_province", "a");
  $query->fields("a", array('id', 'name'));
  $query->condition("a.status", 1);
  $query->orderBy("a.name");
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($row = $result->fetchObject()){
    $province[$row->id] = $row->name;
  }

  return $province;
}


function _load_city($province_id) {
  $city = array('- Select city -');

  $query = db_select("sandbox_city", "a");
  $query->fields("a", array('id', 'name'));
  $query->condition("a.status", 1);
  $query->condition("a.province_id", $province_id);
  $query->orderBy("a.name");
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($row = $result->fetchObject()){
    $city[$row->id] = $row->name;
  }

  return $city;
}
```